# How to disable the "background-attatchment: fixed" when it will cause an error

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I have looked all over stack overflow about this question and have found various answers, but none of them fit my needs. I have my background-attatchment set as 'fixed' but as most know this bugs out on ios devices. Is there a way that I can just set the property to 'scroll' when it won't work? If the property is set to 'scroll' from the beginning the picture doesn't resize and do funky things.

I have tried various solutions including '@supports', using web-kits, and other stackOverflow suggested solutions... none of them have worked. I would love either a workaround or even just to have the feature work when it can and be disabled when it can't.

Here's my CSS

```
.sectionHeader{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

And here is one of the div's that this is being applied to:

```
    <div id="welcome">
        <div id="jumboName" class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid sectionHeader d-flex align-items-center" style="background-image: url('data/welcome.JPG');">
            <div class="row mx-auto my-auto align-items-center">
                <p class="display-3" style="color:WHITESMOKE; text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;">Name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Again, the goal for this is either to find a work around, or simply to not have the code break on phones while still haveing the effect on computers. This already happens on most web browsers where it defaults the background style to 'scroll' (brave, opera, and a few others) when it cannot handle the property. Just stupid ios devices aren't smart enough to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a good answer! The only browsers (that I know of) that do not use this feature are mobile devices. Because of this we can use a media query.

```
@media (hover: none) {
    .sectionHeader{
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

Using this, we can set the background-attachment property to fixed except when there is no hover enabled on the device.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a way to detect a glitch like that.